# Buck Converter Switching Loop Area in Layout Should be small

Tags: voltage, current, dc-dc-converter, buck, layout

I have seen recommendations in the datasheets of buck converters, that the switching loop area should be as small as possible. Can someone help me on what would happen if the switching area is large and how it might or cause harmonics?

Or rather, whether a large switching loop area would cause harmonics?

Can someone help me to understand the concept behind it , if possible some visualization with a 3D cross section of a PCB, please.

Comment: "*Or rather, whether a large switching loop area would cause harmonics?*" This isn't quite right. It doesn't cause harmonics. It aggravates the noise caused by high frequency currents (like harmonics), if there are any to begin with. It's like a winding road. It doesn't cause cars. It causes traffic jams, but only if there are cars that needed to go somewhere to begin with. Whether or not there are cars needing to go somewhere is not affected by the fact that the road is straight or winding.

Comment: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slvaed3/slvaed3.pdf?ts=1624096779590&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F Hope this link will be useful to understand better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea is to eliminate parasitic inductance and resistance in places with high di/dt currents.  Since V=L*di/dt, extra unwanted inductance can create ringing, EMI,  and large voltage spikes which may impact reliability and performance.

For example, the input capacitors on a buck converter can have large fast pulses of current every time the top switch turns on.  If they are far from the drain of the top FET, or not connected solidly to ground, it can cause ringing and EMI.

Also if the source of the lower FET or the output caps are not connected directly to ground with a low impedance, you can have similar problems.  Output ripple an spikes can be much worse if the output caps have additional series inductance due to layout.

Parasitics on the swich node can cause excess ringing which in some cases can exceed the VDS rating on the FET causing reliability issues and EMI.