# What causes harmonics in DC-DC Switching converters like Buck and Boost Converter

Tags: voltage, current, dc-dc-converter, buck, boost

Can someone tell me what and how the harmonics are caused in the DC-DC Switching converters?

I tried to read [this](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/what-is-the-reason-for-harmonics-in-dc-dc-converter.930389/), but I am not understanding. Can someone please explain in simple terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every signal in nature has its own natural harmonics along with itself. Fourier showed that every signal is made up of sine waves having integral multiplies of the natural frequency. This is true, even if the signal itself is a square wave or a random noise, or even an electromagnetic wave.

So, if your switching converter has a switching frequency of, say, 100kHz then it's obvious that there'll be 200kHz, 300kHz, 400kHz sine waves along with the switched voltage or current.

Of course, it's possible to control (e.g. tame) the amplitudes of these sine waves.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you provide some information on how these harmonics might arise?  Like, if the switching freq is 50kHz. And I am observing some harmonic freq of 350kHz, what causes this harmonics to arise? Poor layout, or poor value of components, or something else?

Comment: The layout has a huge impact here. Poor layout can cause unexpected/unwanted oscillations. For example, if you keep the switching loop too long or the area of the loop too big then, due to the parasitic reactive components (e.g. PCB traces, components' leakage/parasitic inductances, etc.), you may observe oscillations. These oscillations don't have to have the integral multiples of the switching frequency. For example, the leakage inductance of the inductor and the Coss of the MOSFET may form a resonance network, so you may end up having different frequencies wandering around.

Comment: So, these oscillations are called ringing, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly they are.

Comment: "Fourier showed that every signal is made up of sine waves having integral multiplies of the natural frequency." I don't see anything in the Fourier transform that says this. Nor am I aware that Fourier ever made that claim. There are many signals which do not contain harmonic components. For example, a perfect sine wave. Or, the sum of two perfect sine waves. The list, obviously, goes on. Of course, there are many signals which do contain harmonics. For example a square wave, as you point out. Also, what do you mean by "natural frequency"? Do you mean fundamental frequency? (1/2)

Comment: If so, what is the fundamental frequency of random noise? (2/2)

Comment: Are you perhaps confused because a Fourier series (relevant for periodic functions) is a sum over a fundamental frequency and all harmonics? This doesn't mean that every periodic signal has those harmonic components.

Comment: Or, is the point that no real world signal is perfect? First, I'm not aware that Fourier showed this (if he did please provide a source). As far as I know, the argument that it's theoretically impossible to create a perfect clock signal is new: "Autonomous Quantum Clocks: Does Thermodynamics Limit Our Ability to Measure Time?" Also, how does that imply harmonics? I might be wrong, but I don't think an otherwise perfect sinusoid with random phase or frequency fluctuations would produce harmonics.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with Fourier? How any waveform is composed of the summation of a bunch of sinewaves of appropriate frequencies, amplitude, and phase shifts relative to each other?

DC-DC converters switch a square wave since that is simplest (just an on/off switch). The harmonics are are just all the higher frequency sinusoids beyond the fundamental sinusoid required to produce a sine-wave.

So if your converter is switching at 50kHz, since it is just switching on/off to produce a square wave, that square wave is composed of a 50kHz sinusoid, and other sinusoids of higher frequency which are all odd multiples of 50kHz(50kHz x3, 50kHz x5, 50kHz x7...). These are the harmonics and in an ideal square wave they go up to an odd multiple of infinite. If you add all these up and they have the appropriate amplitudes and phase shifts, you'll get a square wave.

The more harmonics you add the closer your approximation of a real square wave:

There is an animation of it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Fourier_series_for_square_wave.gif

[image]

http://www.sigcon.com/Pubs/edn/TaketheFifth.htm

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I have read the fourier and understand that many sinusoids are combined to get a particular square wave. So, switching frequency is the only source of the harmonics. Am I right? Could you provide some information on how these harmonics might arise?  Like, if the switching freq is 50kHz. And I am observing some harmonic freq of 350kHz, what causes this harmonics to arise? Poor layout, or poor value of components, or something else?

Comment: See my comment in your other question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/571943/buck-converter-switching-loop-area-in-layout-should-be-small It seems you're a bit confused between noise and harmonics. Bad layout doesn't cause harmonics. It aggravates noise if there are harmonics. Harmonics are inherent to the operation of the switch. No harmonics = NO SQUARE WAVE!

Comment: Yes, I am definitely confused. I am not sure my questions are properly worded. But my basic doubt is that, how would you get harmonics? Like, I understand that the switching frequency is the source. But, my question is like, if for the switching frequency of 50kHz, the possible harmonics are the positive odd multiple of 50kHz. But what actually decides which harmonic is emitted? Like which factor decides whether the harmonic frequency is 50kHz*3 or 50kHz*9 or 50kHz*n (n being any odd number)? Which decides this harmonic frequency?

Comment: @Newbie I mean, if that's your question that comes down to just the way the world works (i.e. the way the math works). That just happens to be combination that produces a square wave. Other combinations produce other waves. It's on par with asking what makes it a circle have all its edges be the same point away from a single point? Or what makes rectangles and squares tessellate?

Comment: Yes, this was my actual question on which harmonic would be selected and emitted. I was thinking like, the reason that a particular harmonic is selected is might be because of an improper value of a component or some poorly designed PCB layout or something else? So, these might not be the factors that would decide which harmonic would be emitted?

Comment: What determines the harmonics present is the waveshape that is produced by whatever physical process is happening. In a switch, it is a square/rectangular wave but not an ideal one since that would require infinitely fast edges. Inductance, capacitance, and the physical processes that determine how fast the switch transition between on and off will determine the exact harmonics produced. So a switch that transition faster will produce more harmonics which will in turn produce more noise if the layout is poor. But the layout being poor by itself doesn't produce harmonics.

Comment: @Newbie No, like it is already said, switching signal is a square wave, and thus a 50 kHz square wave contains harmonics of 50 kHz.